# Java 8: How to create OptionalInt from Optional<Integer>

Tags: java-8, option-type

How to create OptionalInt from Optional in an elegant way?

```
Optional<Integer> int1 = Optional.of(1);
OptionalInt int2 = ??;
```

Comment: `int1.map(OptionalInt::of).orElseGet(OptionalInt::empty)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider what is better, your answer or `int1.map(OptionalInt::of).orElse(OptionalInt.empty())` which is just slightly different but has the same output

Comment: Mine. I don't create the `empty` if I don't need to. Although in practice both are the same as empty always returns the same instance.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yeah you're right, it doesn't make a big difference. But thanks anyway!